# How to display the number of images in instagram

Tags: instagram, instagram-api, instagram-graph-api, instagram-story

Currently in my instagrams display 7 photos and this is "Data"

=> http://prntscr.com/td4enf

Now I want to show only 4 photos in my instragarm. My old way

https://api.instagram.com/v1/users/ '. esc_attr ($ id). '/ media / recent /? access_token ='. esc_attr ($ token). '& count ='. esc_attr ($ limit))

I used "& count" to handle this piece in the old version.

in the new version I used the path

=> https: //graph.instagram.com/me? fields = id, username & access_token = IGQVJ ...
To retrieve data.

I use "& count" for the new version but it doesn't work. Can you help me with this problem, how should I handle it? I want it to display 4 images instead of 7 default images.

Answer (score 0):

As of now, instagram APIs are changed. You need to get media id as described here https://developers.facebook.com/docs/instagram-api/reference/user/media#get-media and after of that you need to call API for each media post and get image and other post details. Here you can restrict your API calls.